# black backgrounds on options panels

Tags: window

So, somewhere along my linux-ing, I must have messed something up, because on a lot of the settings windows (not all), where there should be a white background, there is a black one.
 Oddly, though, after taking a screenshot of the windows, They seem to have transparent, not black, backgrounds...

As an example, here's what the "Details" panel looks like:

Here's what a screenshot gives me:[image]

And here's what I actually see:[image]

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Remove Windows. Your welcome!

Comment: Haha, already done. I mean the window that things run in, whatever that's called on linux. For instance, the "Details" menu in system settings is pretty much unreadable, because the background of it is black, and the text is very dark gray.

Comment: Oh, I totally misunderstood you. I though you were talking about the OS. Please, edit your question and make it more clear. If you can add screenshoots (upload to imgur.com and link it). Tip: use breaklines!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had [the same problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450209/black-spaces-in-panels-windows-dialog/450216?noredirect=1#450216).

This can be fixed by uninstalling `overlay-scrollbar`. This will remove overlay scrollbars though.

You can uninstall it by executing `sudo apt-get remove overlay-scrollbar`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It worked! However, I've switched to Kubuntu already, since KDE windows don't seem to be affected.