# Black spaces in panels/windows/dialogs

Tags: window

A lot of windows look have black spaces everywhere like this:

[image: Gnome Tweak Tool Appearance with Black Spaces]

However, when I take a screenshot, the black space is replaced with transparency, and the screenshot looks like this:

[image: Gnome Tweak Tool Appearance Screenshot]

This isn't that bad but it gets more annoying when stuff like this happens:

[image: Gnome Tweak Tool Typing with Black Spaces]

[image: Details Dialog with Black Spaces]

It also has nothing to do with the theme I'm using (Numix). The same happens with Adwaita.

[image: Notifications dialog with Black Spaces with Adwaita theme.]

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug. It sometimes disappears after you uninstall the package `overlay-scrollbar`. This will, evidently, also remove the overlay scrollbars.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't really like overlay scrollbars anyway so it works great!

Comment: Can you please link the known bug? Thx

Comment: This one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1059374